# How to make a youtube link as embed?

Tags: java, jsp, substring

```
<%
String song = request.getParameter("songname");
String band = request.getParameter("band");
String url = request.getParameter("url");
%>
<div align="center">
    <br><br>  <% out.print(band + " - " + song); %><br><br>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%out.print(url);%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<%
%>
```

Let's say url i get is like this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXYiU_JCYtU i want to make it look like https://www.youtube.com/embed/kXYiU_JCYtU  this so i can put it at src=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` method:

```
<% out.print(url.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")); %>
```

Comment: @KazaMaster You should really take some time to read the JavaDocs on the common classes, like `String` and the various collection classes. And in general, if you're not sure how to do something with some type, the JavaDoc should be your first stop.